Filter non adjacent columns for dates and outputting results for the months (6 months)
Hi  i am trying to use the filter function to filter 6 different columns which have dates to use with a search box and work out values for months of the year  with drop down box which  i have done  .  everything works fine  with the 1 filter and 1 column but i am having trouble  trying to add the other columns. (non adjacent)
I am using MS Office 2021
The filters i am using are
i have spent hours trying to get formula right but am still having trouble   here is the formula  i have ended up with but i get the  #VALUE! error
When  i use the filter formulas on their own it works for the one column but i cannot work out how to combine them
The individual filters are
=FILTER(Data,(Data!S4:S1002>=Dashboard!AB4)*(Data!S4:S1002<=Dashboard!AC4),"")
=FILTER(Data,(Data!U4:U1002>=Dashboard!AB4)*(Data!U4:U1002<=Dashboard!AC4),"")
=FILTER(Data,(Data!W4:W1002>=Dashboard!AB4)*(Data!W4:W1002<=Dashboard!AC4),"")
=FILTER(Data,(Data!Y4:Y1002>=Dashboard!AB4)*(Data!Y4:Y1002<=Dashboard!AC4),"")
=FILTER(Data,(Data!AA4:AA1002>=Dashboard!AB4)*(Data!AA4:AA1002<=Dashboard!AC4),"")
=FILTER(Data,(Data!AC4:AC1002>=Dashboard!AB4)*(Data!AC4:AC1002<=Dashboard!AC4),"")
and they work  but when  itry to combine them like below am getting stuck.
=FILTER(Data,(Data!S4:S1002,Data!U4:U1002,Data!W4:W1002,Data!Y4:Y1002,Data!AA4:AA1002,Data!AC4:AC1002>=Sheet1!AB4)*(Data!S4:S1002,Data!U4:U1002,Data!W4:W1002,Data!Y4:Y1002,Data!AA4:AA1002,Data!AC4:AC1002<=Sheet1!AC4),"")
and i tried
=FILTER(Data,(Data!S4:S1002,Data!U4:U1002,Data!W4:W1002,Data!Y4:Y1002,Data!AA4:AA1002,Data!AC4:AC1002>=Sheet1!AB4)*(Data!$S$4:$S$1002,Data!$U$4:$U$1002,Data!$W$4:$W$1002,Data!$Y$4:$Y$1002,Data!$AA$4:$AA$1002,Data!$AC$4:$AC$1002<=Sheet1!AC4),"")
Any help would be appreciated please to where i am going wrong  or am i using wrong command
Thanking you in advance
